ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile
App I'm working on: https://github.com/mhiga701/safesteps-frontend/tree/beta-test-start
To reproduce:

Clone repo @ url
Run ./setup.sh to install dependencies
Run ./prebuild.sh (which is just npx expo prebuild)

Error:
Error: [ios.xcodeproj]: withIosXcodeprojBaseMod: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/assets/sounds/beep.mp3' -> '/Users/...mypaths.../safesteps-frontend/ios/SafeSteps/beep.mp3'

There is a specific file that expo prebuild is not liking, and I'm not entirely sure why this is the case and also not sure what to try. This is preventing me from incrementing the build number which I need to do to submit to Testflight.

If your error message is accurate, could it be because it's trying to read /assets (as a root directory)?

Aaaaaaaand yup that was pretty much it. I looked in my app.json and it was /assets/blah not ./assets/blah

SOLVED: Make sure to double check paths you set in your app.json folder for certain assets if prebuild is not finding them! Thanks to @J. Titus
